# Rational points on the the reduction mod $p$ of $X_0(N)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

Consider the modular curve $X_0(N)$ over $\mathbb Q$ and for $p\mid N$ consider the reduction modulo $p$ of $X_0(N)$. Let's denote this curve with the symbol $X_p$ (we know that it is a singular curve defined over $\mathbb F_p$).

**Now my question is the following:**  what are the rational points of $X_p$ in terms of the moduli correspondence? To be more precise I would some relation like: a rational point $x\in X_p$ corresponds to an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb F_p$ such that...

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken, there’s no “canonical” reduction $X_p$ – you need to take the fiber of a specific model, and the corresponding $X_p$ will vary. Standard references would be Deligne-Rapoport (*Schémas de modules de courbes elliptiques*) or Katz-Mazur (*Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves*), but I’m not sure if they actually address the “reduction mod $p$” part. If $N/p$ is coprime to $p$, I think that (for the regular minimal model?) $X_0(N)$ mod $p$ is two copies of $X_0(N/p)$ (mod $p$ – it has good reduction) meeting at the supersingular points.

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb{F}_p(X_0(m)_p)/\Bbb{F}_p(X_0(pm)_p)$ a purely inseparable extension so there is a one to one correspondence between their points (I mean the smooth curve with function field $\Bbb{F}_p(j(q),j(q^m)) \subset \Bbb{F}_p((q))$ so that  $\Bbb{F}_p(j(q),j(q^{pm}))=\Bbb{F}_p(j(q),j(q^{m})^p)$)

Comment: Are supersingular points rational?

Comment: If the $j$-invariant is rational, and they have a rational (ie Galois-equivariant) cyclic subgroup of order $N/p$, then yes. So, sometimes.